# How to set up a If is_singular statement?

Tags: php, theme-development

I've got this code here, and I want it to exclude this div from being parsed if the condition is false.

```
<?php if ( ! is_single() ) { ?>
    <div class="cat-container">
        <a class="post-cat bg-darkpurple" href="<?php echo $category_link ?>"><?php echo $category_name ?></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

However, It does not work as intended. It's either true or false for all results depending on if ! is included or not. I feel like I'm missing something really simple.

Basically, I don't want the div to be sent to the loop If it is a page, not a post(Since pages don't have categories.)

I've tried is_single, Is_singluar, and ('post') in there as well, to no avail.

Thanks for any insight

Comment: Is it just that the logic is wrong?  You're saying if it's NOT `is_single()`, but your explanation says you DO want it loading on single posts.   Try this instead `if( is_single( 'post' ) ) {`
You want to exclude the DIV if it's false, but you're actually including it ONLY if it's false.

Comment: If I reverse it, it disables the div even if the post type is single. It's all true or all false.

Comment: Are you calling it within a template?  We're missing something simple here... ...not sure what.

Comment: It is being called within a loop in the search.php file.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/357650/adjust-the-results-quantity-for-search-results-page-pagination?noredirect=1#comment521373_357650

This has the code in question.

Comment: Ok, that's the issue - the search.php is neither a page nor a post so your logic instead has to execute on each of the returned items.  Instead of `is_single()` you want to instead check if it's a *post* for each of the returned search results, so instead try `if ( get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) == 'post' ) { //if is true }`.  Want me to put it into an answer?  Also, I assume this is executing within the `while( have_posts() ) : the_post();`?

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_single()` and `is_singular()` are not the correct functions to use here.

Your comment mentions that this is being added to `search.php`, but `is_single()` and `is_singular()` will always be false on `search.php`, because those functions are checking if the current page is a single post or page, but `search.php` is not. It's is a *list of multiple results*. `is_single()` is not checking the current item in a loop, it's checking, essentially, what is represented by the current *URL*.

This is why it's displaying for `! is_single()`, because `is_single()` is `false`, and `! false` is `true`.

If you need to determine the post type of a post within a loop, you can use `get_post_type()`:

```
<?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) { ?>
    <div class="cat-container">
        <a class="post-cat bg-darkpurple" href="<?php echo $category_link ?>"><?php echo $category_name ?></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Both yours and Tony's solution works! Thank you :)